# Touch event not firing on iOS <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, mobile

I have a link on my web page that opens to a new tab using `target="_blank"`.  It also has a `click` event bound to it should fire also when the user clicks the link.

However, on mobile (right now testing with Chrome on iOS7), I can't seem to get this event to fire when the user clicks the link.  The link opens in a new tab as it should, but the event doesn't seem to fire—though when I test in mobile emulator on Chrome, it does.  I have tried binding to the `click`, `touchstart`, and `touchend` events, and none of them seem to work.

**How can I also get a click or touch event to fire when a user clicks an `<a target="_blank">` tag on mobile?**

---

Below is the code I've used so far.  Though the project is in Angular, I've provided both Angular and jQuery versions, since the event handlers aren't Angular-specific.

Angular version (including `ngTouch` in the project):

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://external-link.com" target="_blank"
   ng-click="functionToBeCalled()"
    >Click me!</a>
```

Angular version 2:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://external-link.com" target="_blank"
       on-touch="functionToBeCalled()"
        >Click me!</a>

<script>
    angular.module('myModule').directive('onTouch', function () {
        return {
            scope: {onTouch: '&'},
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {elem.bind('touchstart', function(){scope.onTouch();});}
        }
    });
</script>
```

Equivalent in jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#mylink').bind('touchstart', function () {
        console.log("Touch event was fired!");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the  element overrides the touch event handling you do.
Why do you want to fire a touch event and have a default link behavior at the same time?

You could do a preventDefault:

```
 <script>
 $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
   open link here with function
   handle touch here with function
 });
 </script>
```

And handle everything with a script. You can launch the link in a new window from there via script and fire your touch event from there, too.

Comment: Click tracking is the main reason.  Thanks!n was hoping to avoid opening the new tab with JavaScript because of potential browser popup blocking behavior.